# why I cannot copy .pc to the /usr/lib/pkg-config folder under MacOS?

Tags: pkg-config

I am the root and use the command to copy a file to /usr/lib/pkgconfig

## cp /usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.4/share/pkgconfig/eigen3.pc .

Password:
cp: ./eigen3.pc: Operation not permitted

I checked the directory, root should have write permission,

```
drwxr-xr-x  15 root  wheel       510 Apr  8 13:29 pkgconfig
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OS X 10.11, this could be due to System Integrity Protection (SIP).

[SIP - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection)

`Among the protected directories are: /System, /bin, /sbin, /usr (but not /usr/local).`

To Disable

[StackExchange article to disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11)